# How can I add different attributes to the account on ASP.NET?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, azure, asp.net-mvc-5

So I am following this tutorial:
https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/web-sites-dotnet-deploy-aspnet-mvc-app-membership-oauth-sql-database/#create-an-aspnet-mvc-5-application

and I was wondering how do I go about adding more things to the account? Like when I register it asks for email and password, but how would I add a name field (with database storage of course) ?

Comment: how do I change values from Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework ? http://imgur.com/pjYEjcW

Answer (score 1):

You can use the Profile Variables.

From MSDN

> In many applications, you want to store and use information **that is
>   unique to a user.** When a user visits your site, you can use the
>   information you have stored to present the user with a personalized
>   version of your Web application. Personalizing an application requires
>   a number of elements: you must store the information using a unique
>   user identifier, be able to recognize users when they visit again, and
>   then fetch the user information as needed. To simplify your
>   applications, **you can use the ASP.NET profile feature**, which can
>   perform all of these tasks for you.

[Introduction to Membership](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yh26yfzy.aspx)

[ASP.NET Profile Properties Overview](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/2y3fs9xs.aspx)